# What is IF-MIB: snimpy.mib.SMIException: unable to find b'IF-MIB' (check the path)?

Tags: python, snmp, mib, snimpy

I followed [the doc](https://snimpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#regular-python-module) but got the following error:

```
>>> from snimpy.manager import Manager as M
from snimpy.manager import load

load("IF-MIB")
m = M("localhost")
print(m.ifDescr[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/home/ed8/projects/coaxis-opt/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snimpy/manager.py", line 578, in load
    m = mib.load(mibname)
  File "/home/ed8/projects/coaxis-opt/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snimpy/mib.py", line 605, in load
    raise SMIException("unable to find {0} (check the path)".format(mib))
snimpy.mib.SMIException: unable to find b'IF-MIB' (check the path)
```

#### Question

What is `IF-MIB`? Do I need to install some package on my system?

#### Reference

[Doc example fails: snimpy.mib.SMIException: unable to find b'IF-MIB' (check the path)](https://github.com/vincentbernat/snimpy/issues/57)

Answer (score 0):

As provided by [snimpy developer](https://github.com/vincentbernat/snimpy/issues/57#issuecomment-248692852):

> If you are on Ubuntu, you need to
>
> ```
> apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader
> ```